# Tell the maven to not set the classpath in dependecies

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm using Maven plugins to build JAR and set the manifest:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>...</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

It works fine, but the problem is: i don't wanna add classpathPrefix when the JAR is copying as dependency to another JAR, only when it builds itself.
How to tell Maven to not set classpathPrefix when copy-dependencies?